# Call to Javascript function with in dynamically created HTML <a> tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

This seemed to be a simple javascript but I feel so dumb to ask this question.. but I don't know why this is not working. I have a method that dynamically creates some hyperlinks on the page. The hyperlinks are suppose to call an executable with a url as parameter. So, I use href with a call to this function that has the code to call the executable.

Non-dynamic anchor tag code works just fine to launch an exe.

But, I need this to work with dynamic hyperlinks. I have tried to simplify the problem and created the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fw56g/1/) to demonstrate the issue. The link doesn't call my method. Am I missing something stupid? I want this to work in IE.

I already tried some solutions posted by some people saying:  I should try `href="#" onclick="myfunc();"`. Somehow that didn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
function myfunc(url){
    alert(url);
};

function dynfunc(){
    var value = "This is a link";
    var url="http://www.google.com";
    var table = $("<table id='tab1'></table>");
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    var valueColumn = $("<td></td>");
    $('<a href="javascript: myfunc(\'' + url + '\');"></a>').html(value).appendTo(valueColumn);

    valueColumn.appendTo(row);
    row.appendTo(table);
    $("#div1").append(table);
};

dynfunc();
```

Comment: Try: `$('<a href=#/>').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); myfunc(url) })` instead.

Comment: Do you really need that link to be in a table? What is the point? I would just make an `click` function on the link.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the responses. Regarding the table, actually this example is just a little part of what I am actually doing. So yes, I need table.

Comment: I just want to let user2246674 know that the solution provided by you worked in just one go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this html :

```
<table id="dyn">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can just use this JavaScript for the Dynamicly added `<a/>`, this way you add one click handler instead of several.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var tbl = $('#dyn'), tbody = tbl.find('tbody');

        var addLink = function(url, val) { 
            var tr = $('<tr/>'),
                td = $('<td/>').appendTo(tr),
                a = $('<a/>', {href: url}).html(val).appendTo(td);
        }

        tbl.on('click', 'a', function() {
            alert($(this).attr('href'));
        });

        //some ajax that calls addLink
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/wNGd9/)**

**Change This line :**

```
 $('<a href="javascript: myfunc(\'' + url + '\');"></a>').html(value).appendTo(valueColumn);
```

**To :**

```
 $('<a href="#"></a>').html(value).appendTo(valueColumn).click(function(){myfunc(url) });
```

We associate a `click` event to your `<a>` after `append` and on every click , `myfunc(url)` will be called  .

Comment: I checked and it works great too. I was wondering if it will be better that what OneOfOne suggested? I know having one event handler is always better.